# Prime numbers in interval in Python using Eratosthenes sieve

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder how I could implement Eratosthenes sieve algorithm but in specific range in Python, can't find solution for this problem so far.

Here's my code, it works but I need to implement sieve to make it much more faster:

```
def primes(m, n):
    primes = []
    if m > 2 and n >= m:
        for num in range(m, n + 1):
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                primes.append(num)
    return(primes)
```

And I get proper output:

```
[101, 103, 107, 109]
```

Comment: This is referred to as a segmented sieve and [algorithm and code for segmented sieve](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segmented-sieve-print-primes-in-a-range/).  Your code is a simple trial division so unrelated to a sieve algorithm.

Comment: read this [Segmented Sieve](https://medium.com/@dhruvhimself/generate-prime-numbers-in-python-using-segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes-245b79da6687)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is generate a normal sieve up to the square root of `n`.  While you are generating that normal sieve update another sieve that corresponds to the range `m`...`n`:

For example:

```
def primeRange(a,b):
    sieve    = [1]*(int(b**0.5)+2)  # normal sieve
    abSieve  = [1]*(b-a+1)          # range sieve
    p,np     = 1,2                  # prime candidate
    while np<len(sieve):
        p,np = np,p+2
        if not sieve[p]: continue   # seek next prime
        sieve[p*p::p]     = [0]*len(sieve[p*p::p])     # update normal sieve
        first             = max(p*p-a,(p-a%p)%p)       # 1st offset in range
        abSieve[first::p] = [0]*len(abSieve[first::p]) # update range sieve
    return [ p for p,s in enumerate(abSieve,a) if s ]  # return primes in range
```

output:

```
r = primeRange(100,110)
print(r)

# [101, 103, 107, 109]

r = primeRange(100000000000000,100000000000100)
# [100000000000031, 100000000000067, 100000000000097, 100000000000099]
# (in 3 seconds)
```